# What is the primary purpose of the NinjectServiceHost class?

Tags: .net, ninject

At first I thought using NinjectServiceHost class was the only way to create, for example, a non-default service implementation class instance. (Out of the box you can only call new ServiceHost(typeof(SomeClass)), where SomeClass would be instantiated using a parameterless constructor, which doesn't allow any dependency injection).

But now I see that I can simple use Ninject kernel to retrieve a singleton instances of easily testable classes (that don't implement singleton explicitly, rather I would use InSingletonScope binding of Ninject) from within my service class.

What is the main use of NinjectServiceHost? What features does it provide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer apears to be the following:

If I don't use a NinjectServiceHost to host a WCF service, my service class would have to be Ninject-aware to resolve it's dependencies in code.

Using NinjectServiceHost allows to pass a constructor parameters to a service class, thus allowing it to be independent of Ninject.